# Installing Solr 6.5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04; can't access admin UI

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, solr

I am trying to install Solr on an Ubuntu server. I followed this guide:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-solr-on-ubuntu-1604/

Everything appeared to work, except I cannot access the Solr admin. Attempting to access `http://(server ip):8983/solr` results in a timeout / server not responding style message.

Running `sudo ufw status` shows 'status inactive'.

What is blocking access to the admin?

Comment: Are you sure Solr is actually running and listening on that port?

Comment: Solr is running, I restarted the service a few times and is running the defaults so it is using that port. What else could I try? Are file permissions incorrect for the solr directory?

Comment: Use `ss` or `netstat` to **confirm** that Solr is listening on that port and IP-address; you may have  solr admin interface that only binds on localhost i.e. 127.0.0.1 and then you either need to explicitly change that in your config or use SSH port forwarding to connect to the admin port...

Comment: netstat reports: "tcp6       0      0 [::]:8983               [::]:*                  LISTEN" and ss reports: "tcp    LISTEN     0      50     :::8983                 :::* "

Comment: Maybe you're running with IPv6 addresses exclusively? But otherwise I would expect a second match for a listener on IPv4 in the netstat/ss output

Comment: I did an ssh port forward for now... `ssh -L 8983:localhost:8983 USER@IP -N` and I can access it... would like to know how to access it from a hostname though.